# Code doesn't work correctly replacing one character in a string with another

Tags: c, string, function, char

I have this program that asks the user for an input string and two characters. One character to be replaced and the other that will replace the old one. I call a function named `replace()` that loops through the string, looking for the old character and replacing it with the new character. It prints the new string in `main()`, but it doesn't work right. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void replace(char string[], char old, char new);

int main()
{
    char input[100], newChar, oldChar;
    char newstr[100];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);


    printf("Enter a character to replace: ");
    scanf("%c", &oldChar);

    printf("Replace character with?: ");
    scanf("%c", &newChar);
    getchar();

    replace(input, oldChar, newChar);

    printf("Result: %s\n", input);


}

void replace(char string[], char old, char new)
{
    int length = strlen(string);
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(string[i] == old)
        {
            string[i] = new;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &oldChar);` --> `scanf("%c", &oldChar);getchar();`

Comment: Wooaahh. Tried it out. It worked. Thanks :D

Comment: Or `scanf("%c", &newChar);` --> `scanf(" %c", &newChar);`.

Comment: Note that one of the most basic debugging techniques is "print the inputs to ensure you got what you expected".  If you had printed the characters, you would have seen the trouble.

Comment: @CoolGuy How do you replace with the space ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh. In that case, your solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I think a getchar is missing:

```
printf("Enter a character to replace: ");
scanf("%c", &oldChar);
getchar();

printf("Replace character with?: ");
scanf("%c", &newChar);
getchar();
```